# Binary literals whose value is determined during compile time in C++

Tags: c++, literals

How can i define constant value binary literal whose value is determined during compile time without using preprocessor directives?

I've tried this

```
#include <iosteam>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
const int x=0b0101;

cout<<x;

return 0;

}
```

And it prints out 5, however, i don't know of it's value is determined during compile time. How can i even check that? Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "if the value is determined during compile time"? The value of `x` (could be argued to be determined *before* compile time, by the author of the code), the string that gets printed, etc..

Comment: Didn't the compiler complain that header "iosteam" is not found when you tried that?

Comment: @harold well, i mean that i need it to be compile-time constant

Comment: @ÖöTiib No, it compiled just fine, btw, whats wrong with this much downvotes on question?

Comment: @cdummie sure, an integer literal is as compile-time constant as it gets

Answer (score 1):

`const` "variables" that are initialized at definition are typically also compile-time constants. But if you want to be really sure use `constexpr` instead of `const`:

```
constexpr int x=0b0101;
```

Comment: So basically, even with const i can say that it is compile time constant, now, what if i declared it without const or constexpr?

Comment: @cdummie Without `const` it's just a plain run-time variable. The compiler *might* optimize its use as a compile-time constant if it can safely determine that it's never modified and is only used in a context where it's possible, but otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can check the disassembled code to see what happens, and there is a site for that too, https://godbolt.org/

Typing

```
int main()
{
  const int x=0b0101;
  return 0;
}
```

there and disabling optimization (the -O[x] switch), produces something like this:

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 5
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

`5` appears as an immediate value in the code, obviously provided there by the compiler.
As you asked somewhere else: it is the same without `const` too, the CPU does not care if some entity with an address is meant to be constant or not. For example `const_cast<>` is not an actual operation, it is just a marker for the compiler.